# My python condition checking the input from user is a negative number doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write a code in python to ask a user to input a number and check if is it less than or equal to zero and print a sentence then quit or otherwise continue if the number is positive , also it checks if the input is a number or not

here is my code

```
top_of_range = input("Type a number: ")

if top_of_range.isdigit():
    top_of_range = int(top_of_range)

    if top_of_range <= 0:
        print ("please enter a nubmer greater than 0 next time.")
        quit()

else:
    print(" please type a number next time.")
    quit()
```

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't think `-` counts as a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the help on the `isdigit` method descriptor says:

> Return True if the string is a digit string, False otherwise.
> A string is a digit string if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character in the string.

When you pass a negative number, e.g. `-12`. All characters in it are not a digit. That is why you're not getting the desired behavior.

You can try something like the following:

```
top_of_range = input("Type a number: ")

if top_of_range.isdigit() or (top_of_range.startswith("-") and top_of_range[1:].isdigit()):
    top_of_range = int(top_of_range)

    if top_of_range <= 0:
        print ("please enter a nubmer greater than 0 next time.")
        quit()

else:
    print(" please type a number next time.")
    quit()
```

Based on Mark's comment, if we employ the EAFP principle it will look something like this:

```
top_of_range = input("Type a number: ")

try:
    top_of_range = int(top_of_range)

    if top_of_range <= 0:
        print ("please enter a nubmer greater than 0 next time.")
        quit()
except ValueError:
    print(" please type a number next time.")
    quit()
```

Comment: In Python it's considered better to just do the conversion and detect an error with try/except rather than qualify the input first. It's called the EAFP principle.